# Python Modules doesnot show after install

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to install the project https://github.com/alvations/pywsd  using setup.py command

```
sudo python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pywsd-1.0.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pywsd-1.0.egg-info
```

After installing, the module is available at **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/**

But when i am trying to import **pywsd** in a pything script file by the way

```
import sys
import getopt
import pywsd
```

the pywsd module is not auto suggested at the time of typing and if i  forcedly write `import pywsd` , it finds its location at **/dist-packages/** folder . But when i run the file 
it shows the  error **import pywsd 
ImportError: No module named pywsd**

Comment: probably a different python version. use virtualenv

Comment: A guess: are you running a Python 3 environment? pywsd seems to be installed for 2.7 only.

Comment: I use python 2.7 , i guess "sudo python setup.py install" command is required before install , what u think about this ?